# React Application not rendering components when using the NavBar

Tags: reactjs, state, react-router-dom, data-mapping, react-bootstrap-nav

> EDIT: I am using React 18.2.0 and React router dom 5.3.3, and I recently replaced React.Strictmode with Fragment this evening in my index.jsx file.

As title says, the application is working well except for the NavBar. When you click the sections it does not render the component onto the page, but the href changes in the browser itself. Here is my NavBar component code:

```
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled, { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components';
import endpoints from '../constants/endpoints';
import ThemeToggler from './ThemeToggler';

const styles = {
  logoStyle: {
    width: 50,
    height: 40,
  },
};

const ExternalNavLink = styled.a`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkColor};
  &:hover {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkHoverColor};
  }
  &::after {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.accentColor};
  }
`;

const InternalNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkColor};
  &:hover {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkHoverColor};
  }
  &::after {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.accentColor};
  }
  &.navbar__link--active {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkActiveColor};
  }
`;

const NavBar = () => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(endpoints.navbar, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setData(res))
      .catch((err) => err);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Navbar
      fixed="top"
      expand="md"
      bg="dark"
      variant="dark"
      className="navbar-custom"
      expanded={expanded}
    >
      <Container>
        {data?.logo && (
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">
            <img
              src={data?.logo?.source}
              className="d-inline-block align-top"
              alt="main logo"
              style={
                data?.logo?.height && data?.logo?.width
                  ? { height: data?.logo?.height, width: data?.logo?.width }
                  : styles.logoStyle
              }
            />
          </Navbar.Brand>
        )}
        <Navbar.Toggle
          aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"
          onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
        />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto" />
          <Nav>
            {data
              && data.sections?.map((section, index) => (section?.type === 'link' ? (
                <ExternalNavLink
                  key={section.title}
                  href={section.href}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
                  className="navbar__link"
                  theme={theme}
                >
                  {section.title}
                </ExternalNavLink>
              ) : (
                <InternalNavLink
                  key={section.title}
                  onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
                  exact={index === 0}
                  activeClassName="navbar__link--active"
                  className="navbar__link"
                  to={section.href}
                  theme={theme}
                >
                  {section.title}
                </InternalNavLink>
              )))}
          </Nav>
          <ThemeToggler
            onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
          />
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

const NavBarWithRouter = withRouter(NavBar);
export default NavBarWithRouter;
```

App.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled, { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components';
import endpoints from '../constants/endpoints';
import ThemeToggler from './ThemeToggler';

const styles = {
  logoStyle: {
    width: 50,
    height: 40,
  },
};

const ExternalNavLink = styled.a`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkColor};
  &:hover {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkHoverColor};
  }
  &::after {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.accentColor};
  }
`;

const InternalNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkColor};
  &:hover {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkHoverColor};
  }
  &::after {
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.accentColor};
  }
  &.navbar__link--active {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.navbarTheme.linkActiveColor};
  }
`;

const NavBar = () => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(endpoints.navbar, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setData(res))
      .catch((err) => err);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Navbar
      fixed="top"
      expand="md"
      bg="dark"
      variant="dark"
      className="navbar-custom"
      expanded={expanded}
    >
      <Container>
        {data?.logo && (
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">
            <img
              src={data?.logo?.source}
              className="d-inline-block align-top"
              alt="main logo"
              style={
                data?.logo?.height && data?.logo?.width
                  ? { height: data?.logo?.height, width: data?.logo?.width }
                  : styles.logoStyle
              }
            />
          </Navbar.Brand>
        )}
        <Navbar.Toggle
          aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"
          onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
        />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto" />
          <Nav>
            {data
              && data.sections?.map((section, index) => (section?.type === 'link' ? (
                <ExternalNavLink
                  key={section.title}
                  href={section.href}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
                  className="navbar__link"
                  theme={theme}
                >
                  {section.title}
                </ExternalNavLink>
              ) : (
                <InternalNavLink
                  key={section.title}
                  onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
                  exact={index === 0}
                  activeClassName="navbar__link--active"
                  className="navbar__link"
                  to={section.href}
                  theme={theme}
                >
                  {section.title}
                </InternalNavLink>
              )))}
          </Nav>
          <ThemeToggler
            onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}
          />
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

const NavBarWithRouter = withRouter
(NavBar);
export default NavBarWithRouter;
```

MainApp.jsx:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import FallbackSpinner from './components/FallbackSpinner';
import NavBarWithRouter from './components/NavBar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import endpoints from './constants/endpoints';

function MainApp() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(endpoints.routes, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setData(res))
      .catch((err) => err);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="MainApp">
      <NavBarWithRouter />
      <Router className="main">
        <Switch>
          <Suspense fallback={<FallbackSpinner />}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            {data
              && data.sections.map((route) => {
                const SectionComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./components/' + route.component));
                return (
                  <Route
                    key={route.headerTitle}
                    path={route.path}
                    component={() => (
                      <SectionComponent header={route.headerTitle} />
                    )}
                  />
                );
              })}
          </Suspense>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainApp;
```

I appreciate any and all help on this, I've been pulling my hair out over it!

Comment: Are you saying the issue is that the URL updates but the page doesn't update/rerender to reflect the correct route content? What ***specific*** versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are installed? You can check by running `npm list react react-router-dom` and report back the ***installed*** version numbers. Also, can you let us know if you are rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component? Does this [answer](/a/71833424/8690857) help?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your response, I added an Edit at the top of the post with that information.

Comment: Is your navigation/rendering issue resolved by upgrading to `react-router-dom@5.3.3`?

Comment: It hasn't unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Actually, besides recommending upgrading to `react-router-dom@5.3.3` or better, the other issue I see is the `NavBar` being rendered ***outside*** the `Router`. Move it *into* the `Router` and remove the `withRouter` HOC. The `withRouter` HOC only injects the route props of the routing context *above* it in the ReactTree and there is none.

NavBar

Instead of

```
const NavBarWithRouter = withRouter(NavBar);
export default NavBarWithRouter;
```

use

```
export default NavBar;
```

...

```
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
...

function MainApp() {
  ...

  return (
    <div className="MainApp">
      <Router className="main">
        <NavBar /> // <-- inside router
        <Switch>
          <Suspense fallback={<FallbackSpinner />}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            {data
              && data.sections.map((route) => {
                const SectionComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./components/' + route.component));
                return (
                  <Route
                    key={route.headerTitle}
                    path={route.path}
                    component={() => (
                      <SectionComponent header={route.headerTitle} />
                    )}
                  />
                );
              })}
          </Suspense>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much!